# How to multi-thread calculation Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to use multi-threading for two different calculation. I have an AsyncTask, which inside have the function "doInBackground". In this function I want to do more calculation exploiting multiple cores. I tried to use IntentService, but I do not know how it works. This is the code of main activity:

```
@Override
public String doInBackground(Void... params) {
   long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   Intent multi_pi = new Intent(
                         getApplicationContext(),
                         multi_pi.class
                    );
   startActivity(multi_pi);
   long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   long total_time = endTime - startTime;
   String time = Long.toString(total_time);
   return time;
}
```

This is the code of the first calculation:

```
public class multi_pi extends IntentService {
   public multi_pi(String pi_1) {
      super(pi_1);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent pi_1) {
    //first calculation
   }
}
```

Is there another solution to do this?

Comment: Why you need IntentService? If you want to multithreaded calculations, just run several AsyncTasks simultaneouslyy.

Comment: Be careful with AsyncTask because it is known to lead to memory leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can't `exploit multiple cores`. Only the system decides whether to use one core or several to solve particular task or tasks.

But you can give a gentle hint to the system that you need to perform several tasks concurrently: just create two or more threads.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        //calculations #1
    }
}).start();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        //calculations #2
    }
}).start();
```

That's all.

Classes like `AsyncTask`, `IntentService` and `Service` have particular aims. If just need to run two threads there is no need to use `AsyncTask` or `IntentService` at all.

Comment: What if I want to calculate the time of execution of singles thread and then add times to a total-time variables?

Comment: @Northumber so what's the problem?

Comment: I want to measure the time of execution of the single calculation until his end, then sum the time to a variable "total-time"